# Ruby: How to call an instance method of a Class from a Module?

Tags: ruby, methods, instance

I have an instance method defined on a class:

```
class Foo
  def is_linux
    # some code...
    # returns true or false
  end
end
```

And i would like to call this method in a Module:

```
class Foo
  module Dog
    is_linux? ? puts "Is Linux" : puts "Is Windows"
  end
end
```

This gives me the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `is_linux?' for Foo::Foo:Module
```

I know i can write

```
class Foo
  module Dog
    Foo.new.is_linux? ? puts "Is Linux" : puts "Is Windows"
  end
end
```

But i was wondering if there is a way for the module to access the current instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'll need somehow to "share" your utility methods.

I would suggest to put them into a mixin:

```
module Mixin
  def is_linux?
    true
  end
end

class Foo
  include Mixin # adding methods at instance level
end

class Foo
  module Dog

    extend Mixin # adding methods at class level

    puts is_linux? ? "Is Linux" : "Is Windows"

  end
end

#=> Is Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option because subtypes (like module) are not connected with their parents instances. If you need such construct you have can only make `is_linux?` class method. If there is no such possibility then propably you have wrong design.